# Is it possible to bookmark the scrollbar in winforms?

Tags: c#, winforms, scrollbar

[image]

I want to let user know about the color located at which position. I'm not sure WinForms able to achieve this but with WPF is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box, a WinForms scrollbar will not have this capability. My advise would be if you want to use WinForms and produce a similar effect, you are best building a custom control based off a scrollbar, implementing the required behaviour yourself within this custom control.

Another option would be to use a third party pre-built control, for e.g. something like [this](https://www.binarymission.co.uk/Products/winforms/MarkerScrollBars.html), a custom built controller with all the associated event handling and methods already built.  Depending on your time, budget and ability, these are your two best options should you want to continue forward using WinForms.